# Split h.264 stream into multiple parts in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, h.264

My objective is to split an h.264 stream into multiple parts, meaning while reading the stream from a pipe i would like to save it into x second long packages (in my case 10).

I am using a **libcamera-vid** subprocess on my Raspberry Pi that outputs the h.264 stream into stdout.
*Might be irrelevant, depends: libcamera-vid outputs a message every frame and I am able to locate it at **isFrameStopLine***
To convert the stream, I use an **ffmpeg** subprocess, as you can see in the code below.

Imagine it like that:
Stream is running...
- Start recording to a file
- *Sleep x seconds*
- Finish recording to file
- Start recording a new file
- *Sleep x seconds*
- Finish recording the new file
- and so on...

Here is my current code, however upon running the first export succeeds, and after the second or third the ffmpeg-subprocess is terminating with the error:
`pipe:: Invalid data found when processing input`
And shortly after, the python process, because of the ffmpeg termination i believe.
`Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/survpi-camera/main.py", line 56, in <module>     processStreamLine(readData)   File "/home/survpi-camera/main.py", line 16, in processStreamLine     streamInfo["process"].stdin.write(data) BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`

```
recentStreamProcesses = []
streamInfo = {
    "lastStreamStart": -1,
    "process": None
}

def processStreamLine(data):
    isInfoLine = ((data.startswith(b"[") and (b"INFO" in data)) or (data == b"Preview window unavailable"))
    isFrameStopLine = (data.startswith(b"#") and (b" fps) exp" in data))
    if ((not isInfoLine) and (not isFrameStopLine)):
        streamInfo["process"].stdin.write(data)
    
    if (isFrameStopLine):
        if (time.time() - streamInfo["lastStreamStart"] >= 10):
            print("10 seconds passed, exporting...")
            exportStream()
            createNewStream()

def createNewStream():
    streamInfo["lastStreamStart"] = time.time()
    streamInfo["process"] = subprocess.Popen([
        "ffmpeg",
        "-r","30",
        "-i","-",
        "-c","copy",("/home/survpi-camera/" + str(round(time.time())) + ".mp4")
    ],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print("Created new streamProcess.")

def exportStream():
    print("Exporting...")
    streamInfo["process"].stdin.close()
    recentStreamProcesses.append(streamInfo["process"])


cameraProcess = subprocess.Popen([
    "libcamera-vid",
    "-t","0",
    "--width","1920",
    "--height","1080",
    "--codec","h264",
    "--inline",
    "--listen",
    "-o","-"
],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

createNewStream()

while True:
    readData = cameraProcess.stdout.readline()
    
    processStreamLine(readData)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Most likely your second file (and others onwards) does not have the metadata needed to play the file. The first file has the SPS, the PPS (and also possibly, the SEI) and it begins with a keyframe. That's why it works... You need your second file too also have a copy of the SPS/PPS/SEI and also have some keyframe as the first frame. You cannot just slice after X seconds, you'll have to scan your data (using a For loop to check values), scan for a keyframe's **start code** (usually `00 00 00 01 65`).. **(1)** Keep SPS/PPS and re-add per new file, **(2)** Use keyframe as a new file's start point

Comment: Maybe a faster solution is to just re-start the process per new file? This way it makes a new file with its own SPS/PPS parameters in the metadata of that file.

Comment: @VC.One Thanks for answering! How would I go about finding the SPS/PPS in the file?

Comment: Open your H264 file in a hex editor. Is the first 5 bytes looking like: `00 00 00 01 67`?

Comment: PS: Start codes for a NALU (packet) is four bytes as `00 00 00 01` then followed by a `67` for SPS, or a `68` for PPS, or a `06` for SEI, or a `65` for a keyframe... **Note::** Some start codes can be 3 bytes long `00 00 01` but that's usually used when following data is non-keyframes and non-metadata. I don't know how yours is setup... What you need to do is take the **first** h264 output and scan its bytes for the position of first keyframe (start of sequence `00 00 00 01 65`), copy everything from data's start (eg: `data[ 0 ]` up to the index of keyframe starting point).

Comment: About second H264 file... First check if it starts with a start code. If not then those starting bytes must belong to a previous frame (before you stopped/restarted your Process). In such cases you want to select everything up to the next keyframe' start code, and cut/paste it at end of the first H264 file. Your second H264 now begins on a keyframe. Paste the SPS and PPS into the start of your second H264 file so that such data is now followed by a keyframe. The second file should work in a media player.

Comment: My point is practice by hand the process of copy/pasting metadata by using a hex editor (for visually editing bytes of a file), then later write Python code to achieve the same result (move bytes, detect start codes, etc)